# Selenium C# WebDriver not resizing browser window correctly

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, browser, resize

I have to make visual tests for test automation purposes, with window browser size being (x=1366,y=668). When I'm running these tests in a headless mode, everything works fine and the window is as large as it should be. However, when I run the same tests WITHOUT headless mode, the browser window always is a bit smaller than it should be.

How can it be made that the window is being sized as it is specified?
Here we can see that the size of the window is not as expected - (1366, 668)

[image]

I have tried to use ChromeOptions for specifying window size.

I have also tried to resize the browser window with this line of code:

```
_driverHelper.Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1366, 668);
```

But so far nothing has worked as expected.

Comment: I remember seeing a post somewhere a while ago that said that Windows always adds something like an 8 pixel border around windows. That seems to math out to pretty close to what you are talking about. Having said that, you are looking at the window size and not the viewport size. Don't you want to set the viewport size to your specific dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use javascript esecutor to try it out

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com/");
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1366, 668);");
```

For me, personally, setting user specific window size in ChromeOptions work just fine.

Please also have a look [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#getSize--). The size of the viewport and the outer window can be a bit confusing at times.